# How to launch Skype using Javascript automatically

Tags: javascript, skype

I know to open skype using its special commands in html to chat, for example:

```
<a href="skype:some_skype_user?chat">Chat</a>
```

One can click on "Chat" and it will launch Skype if it is installed.

However, I want to check if a customer is login to OUR SITE before he is able to chat.  Once the person is login, I would like to launch Skype with a Javascript function so that he does not have to click on the "Chat" link to start Skype.  So basically launching **skype:some_skype_user?chat** automatically.  It must be something simple, but I can't seem to find any answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 'redirecting' to the 'link':

```
window.location = 'skype:some_skype_user?chat';
```

**Edit:** To use a variable in place of `some_skype_user` you need to concatenate it:

```
var skypename = 'skypeuser01';
window.location = 'skype:' + skypename + '?chat';
```

Comment: how do I use a variable in place of some_skype_user in Javascript?

Comment: See the edit above, if you don't know how to concatenate strings in JavaScript (a basic concept) I recommend that you look up the basics as these fundamentals are used heavily when coding. I recommend trying out a codecademy course to help show you the ropes: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitely do that. I am trying to pass the variable as to a function such as: _function myfunction(skypevalue) {
 var skypevalue;
 window.location = 'skype:' + skypevalue + '?chat';
 }_   But it is not working properly

Comment: Remove the `var skypevalue;` as this is reinitializing the variable and overwriting the parameter value.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It is working.  However, I need to check if the user is log in then launch it.  I am now trying to do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312669/how-to-launch-skype-without-being-redirected-by-window-location-in-javascript  but it is forwarding me to the blank page then launch Skype.  Do you know how to do it so it won't forward the user to the blank page?